# sqlite3 boolean field stored as 't', 'f', not compatible with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I have a User table in sqlite3 with schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, 
    "encrypted_password" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,  
    "admin" boolean,);
```

Which has a boolean field admin.

I add a user record from rails console:

```
User.create!({email: "example@example.com", encrypted_password: "sample string", admin:1})
```

Then when I query user record by the admin field

```
select * from users where admin=1;
```

It returns empty result set.

I had a look at sqlite users table, the admin field is saved as string 't' and 'f'.

This cause a problem, when I use custom query in rails, the admin filter is not compatible with sqlite3, which is my test database, and postgresql, which is my dev and production database.

#### How could I overcome this problem?

Comment: that's why you use true and false to query those fields. the database-adapters take care of translating it to the database-specific values for those fields.

Comment: When "admin" is a Boolean column, `select * from users where admin=1;` will raise an error in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', Yes, this is the problem. that means I can't use raw sql query in my code, otherwise the code break in either development or test environment. How can I solve this?

Comment: @phoet, yes, but in my case, I need to use raw sql query, Does it mean I can 't use raw sql cross multiple databases?

Comment: @xiaopang - Rails ActiveRecord has been designed to be db agnostic. However, every time you use custom SQL, you kill it. In most cases, you can write almast any query using active record, eventually falling back to pure arel. In case of this statement it would be simple `User.where(admin: true)`. In short - do not use custom SQL in rails, unless you **reallyy** need to, giving up db-system freedom

Answer (score 2):

If you *must* use raw SQL, then you should use the same dbms in development, testing, and production. PostgreSQL will run fine on Windows, Linux, and OSX.

This is especially important when it comes to SQLite, which doesn't support data types at all in the way SQL databases do. SQLite allows this kind of literal nonsense.

```
sqlite> create table test (n integer not null);
sqlite> insert into test values ('wibble');
sqlite> select n from test;
wibble
```

But the query that's giving you trouble won't run in PostgreSQL anyway. This query

```
select * from users where admin=1;
```

will raise an error in PostgreSQL, because the integer 1 isn't a value in the domain of Boolean values. [The *string* '1' *is* a valid value](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html), though. So this will work.

```
select * from users where admin='1';
```

As will this.

```
select * from users where admin='t';
```

Comment: My query is very complex and cross 3 joined table. that's why I use raw SQL, otherwise construct SQL with activerecord is a pain to me. But now I understand the limit of using raw SQL. Thanks!